# How to remove comma from innerhtml

Tags: javascript

I am writing a code in js to render array of some elements

```
<script>
        const x = ["Karthik", "Mouna", 3, 4, 5];
        const text = document.getElementById('my-text');
        text.innerHTML = `<ul>
                ${x.map(ele => {

            return `<li>${ele}</li>`

        })}
       </ul>`
    </script>
```

I am getting the output as

Karthik
,
Mouna
,
3
,
4
,
5

I need to remove comma from this

i tried

```
<script>
        const x = ["Karthik", "Mouna", 3, 4, 5];
        const text = document.getElementById('my-text');
        text.innerHTML = `<ul>
                ${x.map(ele => {

            return `<li>${ele.toString()}</li>`

        })}
       </ul>`
    </script>
```

Comment: Don't use `innerHTML` for performance and security reasons. Add the content by looping over the array and adding every element by itself.

Comment: Conversely to the comment above, for *performance*, it's generally better to add all your HTML in one go rather than one at a time (that may be via .append instead of .innerHTML) - especially for `<table>` content (not applicable here, but note worthy).

Answer (score 0):

An implementation of tacoshy's comment would be the following:

```
const x = ["Karthik", "Mouna", 3, 4, 5];
const text = document.getElementById('my-text');

// creating the <ul>
const list = document.createElement("ul");

// looping over the array
x.map (ele => {
  let item = document.createElement("li");
  item.textContent = ele;
  // adding each <li> to the <ul>
  list.appendChild(item);
});

// adding the resulting list to the "my-text" div
text.appendChild(list);
```

Edit: I realised I might not be answering your original question. To answer how to remove the commas using your original code, you can add a `.join('')` after `.map` like so:

```
const x = ["Karthik", "Mouna", 3, 4, 5];
const text = document.getElementById('my-text');
text.innerHTML = `<ul>
  ${x.map(ele => {
    return `<li>${ele}</li>`
  }).join("")}
</ul>`;
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is: where do the commas come from?   There's no "," in your code, so why does your output have commas?

The answer is that they are being added when your `.map` results are *implicitly* converted to a string, eg:

```js
const x = ["Karthik", "Mouna", 3, 4, 5];
console.log(""+x)
```

Once you know that, you can remove the "," by converting to the string *explicitly*:

```
${x.map(ele => `<li>${ele}</li>`).join("")}
```

Updated snippet:

```js
const x = ["Karthik", "Mouna", 3, 4, 5];
const text = document.getElementById('my-text');
text.innerHTML = 
`<ul>
  ${x.map(ele => `<li>${ele}</li>`).join("")}
</ul>`
```

```css
ul { list-style: none; }
li { display:inline; padding-right:1em; }
```

```html
<div id='my-text'></div>
```